# Google Analytics: what is "not set" under Network Domain

Tags: google-analytics

I'm looking at Google Analytics. When I view "Network Domain" I see a lot of `(not set)`. What does that mean in terms of the user's network? I'm expecting to see wireless providers, too (e.g., Verizon, Sprint, etc.), but don't. Are wireless providers not captured?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network Domain is derived from a lookup of the user's IP. Most of the time, it will be in a block purchased by an ISP. Sometimes it might be a known company office's IP address range and resolve to their company domain. If it's `(not set)` then the lookup failed to find an associated domain name with the IP address. Either the address has no registered domain or there's no domain associated with the block.

Much like Geolocation, this information is only as accurate and up-to-date as the database source it uses.